# Список выводится в столбец

Tags: python, list

Почему объект типа list выводится в столбец, и как от этого избавиться? (Без `numpy.reshape`, только стандартной библиотекой).

Если использовать `print()`, то все красиво выводит в строку.

[image: ххх]

*на картинке не полный список, но суть вопроса видно*

Comment: это обобенность `iPython`/`Jupyter`... А что вам мешает воспользоваться `print(...)`?

Comment: по большей части, интересуюсь из любопытства)

Comment: протестируйте тут https://hub.mybinder.org/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-zjvnsv72/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb#, если проблема ушла, у вас что-то с настройками, а если нет, то я даже не знаю....

Comment: @NEStenerusnester, ссылка битая, 404 ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` предназначен для вывода данных "как есть", т.е. в том виде, как возвращает метод `__repr__` или `__str__` объекта. Вывод значений в сторонних REPL зависит от того, какой способ вывода решили использовать разработчики. В данном случае похоже что используется [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint):

[image: pprint]

Для списка чисел такой вывод не очень удобен, а вот для списка строк, например, удобнее если каждая строка из списка выводится на отдельной строке на экране.

Т.е. если коротко - просто используйте `print`, когда нужно вывести список в одну строку.